# Enabling javac debugging for Apache ANT

Tags: java, xml, apache, ant, build

Just a simple question. For ANT builds, if I leave the the `debuglevel` parameter completely out will it compile with ALL debugging information? Or would it be better to include `debuglevel="lines,vars,source"` in javac task? I want to enable the maximum level of debugging possible. Here's a snippet:

```
<javac srcdir="${dir.source}"
     destdir="${dir.classes}"
     deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
     debug="${veracode.release.mode}"
     debuglevel="lines,vars,source" <-- should I leave this line out? -->
     optimize="${javac.optimize}">
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you may leave the `debuglevel` attribute out as long as you set the `debug` attribute to `true`.

From the [`javac Ant task`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) documentation:

**debug**

> Indicates whether source should be compiled with debug information; defaults to off. If set to off, -g:none will be passed on the command line for compilers that support it (for other compilers, no command line argument will be used). If set to true, the value of the debuglevel attribute determines the command line argument.

**debugLevel**

> Keyword list to be appended to the -g command-line switch. This will be ignored by all implementations except modern, classic(ver >= 1.2) and jikes. Legal values are none or a comma-separated list of the following keywords: lines, vars, and source. ***If debuglevel is not specified, by default, nothing will be appended to -g.*** If debug is not turned on, this attribute will be ignored.

Therefore, setting `debug` to `true` and omitting `debugLevel` is the same as passing the flag `-g` with no options appended. According to the [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) documentation, passing the `-g` flag with nothing appended is equivalent to specifying sources, lines, and vars.