# Ant arror on upgrade to jdk version 7

Tags: java, debugging, ant, javac, debug-information

I have a ant script which ran successfully with jdk version 6.

```
<javac srcdir="${top}/src" destdir="${clientclasses}" debug="true"
        debuglevel="line" verbose="true" listfiles="true" target="1.5"
        source="1.5"
        includes="client/*.java, common/ApplicationConstants.java">
        <classpath>
            <path path="${output}"/>
            <path refid="classpath_for_src_dir_compile"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

But when I upgraded jdk version to 7, it started giving error saying,

```
-g:line invalid argument to javac
```

I removed `debuglevel=line` and ant script works fine. But I want to keep old behaviour, Is there something java 7 has changed and I need to modify accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `debuglevel="line"` with [correct option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) `debuglevel="lines"`.

It seems Java 6 just ignored incrorrect "line" param and used default "sources, lines, and vars" while Java 7 learned to complain.

You may need just to remove `debuglevel` tag to retain complete debug info as it was before.

See [Enabling javac debugging for Apache ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891194/enabling-javac-debugging-for-apache-ant).